# How do I calculate the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}^2\left ( \pi \frac{t-T}{\pi} \right )$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

How do I calculate the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}^2\left ( \pi \frac{t-T}{\pi} \right )$?

$\frac{\sin t}{t}\;\substack{\mathcal{F}\\ \leftrightarrow} \; \pi \mathrm{rect}\frac \omega 2 = \pi \cdot\begin{cases}0 & \mbox{if } |\omega | > 1 \\\frac{1}{2} & \mbox{if } |\omega | = 1\\1 & \mbox{if } |\omega | < 1. \\ \end{cases}$

and than I would do $sinc(t)^2$ but I always get wrong result.

Comment: Maybe try power reducing formula for sine?

Comment: The transform of a product is the convolution of the transforms of the factors (divided by $2\pi$ for your definition of the Fourier transform). You just need to take the convolution of the unit pulse with itself.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $\text{sinc}^2$ is the [triangle (or *tent*) function](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/triangle.php). The remaining part is easy.